# Reduce Kotlin Android library size

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing an Android library which I target to have a small footprint.

At this moment, just an empty project with Kotlin Coroutines dependencies has 3.29Mb which is not cool at all.

```
Configuration name: "implementation"
Total dependencies size:                   3.29 MB

kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.3.9.jar  1,629.37 KB
kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar               1,472.73 KB
kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar          195.92 KB
kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar             21.83 KB
kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.3.9.jar      19.65 KB
annotations-13.0.jar                      17.13 KB
kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar             15.82 KB
```

How should I use Kotlin and Coroutines for writing a library that has a small footprint?

Comment: Have you tried using proguard ??

Comment: These are transitive dependencies so they aren’t enlarging your library. If you don’t include them, the person using your library would have them anyway if they’re using Kotlin coroutines. If you want to maximize the potential of R8 to minify the project, you can try to avoid using Kotlin standard library functions wherever possible and favor Java methods instead. This is not likely to make much difference because if users of your library are using Kotlin, they will likely be using many of its standard library functions anyway.

Comment: I know this is probably not the best answer to your question, but if your really need to restrict the application size so drastically, then keep things simple and don't use big libraries... like coroutines and kotlin. Kotlin is awesome, but if you have such specific needs, then it probably makes more sense to go with Java and its concurrency utils as they are provided to the application, so you don't need to include them.

Comment: Is there a way I can use gradle to include only exactly code I'm using and everything else get's excluded? Or mark the Kotlin dependencies optional so that in case they are already included in project, they don't get included twice?

Comment: How do you print dependencies size by configuration name?